# Read Bash environment variable in TCL

Tags: tcl

How to read a shell environment variable in your Tcl script.
So anyone please help me. I am very new in TCL.

Answer (score 36):

Use `$::env` to access any environment variables e.g. to access the TMP environment variable do this:

```
set tmpdir $::env(TMP)
```

More info here http://wiki.tcl.tk/1624

Comment: Just i write your code and execute it. But i am not getting. I am in tclsh prompt. My prompt is %. so what i did just type in the prompt % set tmpdir $::env(TMP). The output is like that can't read "::env(TMP)": no such variable

Comment: Actually i want to write a proc is tcl that returns the Bash environment variable values.

Comment: That's because you have no environment variable called TMP. Did you read the link I gave you?

Comment: Ah, I can see the conversation you're having with the other responder - I think you'll be ok!

Answer (score 5):

```
$ export var=42
$ tclsh
% puts $env(var)
42
```

Comment: TMP environment variable is define in the bash script. so what i want to do just access the environment variable in the tcl. my tcl prompt is %. so finally i want to access the environment variable in tcl.

Comment: The TMP enviroment variable would be $env(TMP). **But**: Is the tcl script called from the bash script? Is the variable global (ie. export)?

Comment: Yea. It is working fine. but my question is that what ever environment variable is defined in bash or shell script just i want to access using the proc in tcl. so please........

Comment: yea. TMP variable is the environment variable that is defined in bash script. TMP=/tmp
ORACLE_SID=DBTEST
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/102
export ORACLE_SID ORACLE_HOME
 so here i want to access the environment variable ORACLE_SID  and ORACLE_HOME,  so how i should do, please ........

Comment: So you want a list of _all_ defined shell variables?

Comment: See what i am doing here. I am writing my all steps:

Comment: It's all analogous: The bash variable ORACLE_SID can be accessed using $env(ORACLE_SID) in your tcl script.

Comment: Please just edit your question with the steps, that will be the easiest.

Comment: See what i am doing here. I am writing my all steps: 1. I am using linux 5.0 server. so i am in admin prompt and my prompt is #. My Prompt is [root@db1~] #. 2. after that what i did type tclsh. 3. so now i am in tcl prompt i.e. % (percentage) 4. Type here: su - oracle 5. after that my current working directory is /home/oracle/ and my prompt is $(Dollar). 6. now i again type here tclsh 7. so now i am in % prompt and after that final step 8. puts $env(ORACLE_SID) 7. so here i am getting the exact output DBTEST. so there are the process i am doing here. But what i want i want to write a tcl proc

Comment: so finally i want to write a tcl proc to return the bash environment variable. please help me

Comment: Your problem seems to be the su rather than reading out the variable. You can't just call "su - oracle" inside of a script and read out the bash variables. The easiest way I can suggest is running your tcl script as 'su - oracle -c "tclsh /absolute/path/your-script.tcl"' - you can write a bash wrapper around that of course.

Answer (score 3):

Environment variables are accessible via the built-in global variable `env` (fully qualified it is `::env`). You use this like any other Tcl array.

If you want to print a list of all environment variables you can use something like this:

```
proc dump_env_vars {} {
    foreach name [array names ::env] {
        puts "$name == $::env($name)"
    }
}
```

Of course, to access just a single variable you use it like any other array, for example:

```
puts "HOME = '$::env(HOME)'"
```

For more information see the [env page on the Tcler's wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1624) and [the env section of the tclvars man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/tclvars.htm#M4)

Comment: yea, your procedure is executed, it gives all the environment variables. its ok. But what i am asking here. Suppose in bash script if i define the user define environment like this : ORACLE_SID=DBTEST    ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/102  export ORACLE_SID ORACLE_HOME    Now i want to write a proc in tcl to access the environment variable that is defined by user. so how can i do it. please..........

Comment: I also read u r link. But it is not match with my requirement.

Comment: I just use `parray env` when I want to dump environment variables.

Comment: Here Actually parray is used for print the env values. But what i  want how to access the environment variable in TCL, that is defined in bash script, so please help me......

Answer (score 2):

To read a shell environment variable in Tcl script, try doing something like this:

```
global env
set olddisplay $env(DISPLAY)
set env(DISPLAY) unix:0
```

This might be expressed as well in this fashion:

```
set olddisplay $::env(DISPLAY)
set ::env(DISPLAY) unix:0
```

and forget about `global`.

You can check to see if the variable exists by doing something like:

```
if {[info exists env(VARNAME)]} {
    # okay, it's there, use it
    set value $env(VARNAME)
} else {
    # the environment var isn't set, use a default
    set value "the default value"
}
```

This is [source](http://wiki.tcl.tk/706).